# python open csv files in different folders

Tags: python, csv

I want to read and assign csv files into variables.
But csv files are in different folders.

Here's the thing

```
1. /current/a/1/op/one.csv
2. /current/a/1/no/two.csv
3. /current/a/2/op/three.csv
4. /current/b/1/op/four.csv
```

so I want to assign csv files in `/op`  folders to `grape` by stacking

and I want to assign csv files in `/no`  folders to `apple`

this is my code

```
grape1 = pd.read_csv('current/a/1/op/one.csv')
grape2 =pd.read_csv('current/a/2/op/three.csv')
grape3 = pd.read_csv('current/b/1/op/four.csv')

apple = pd.read_csv('current/a/1/no/two.csv')

grape= grape1+grape2+grape3
```

but I have many files and folders, so my code will be too long.

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop

```
import glob
import panda as pd
df_list = []
for f in glob.glob('current/*/*/op/*.csv'):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv)
grape = pd.concat(df_list)
```